# proper arithmetic operation for two function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to have a addition of two sum of function to get a overall total. but in return they are just combine in one or the results return NAN.

```
//function for display
    function update_price() {
      var row = $(this).parents('.item-row');
      var price = row.find('.cost').val().replace("₱" ,"") * row.find('.qty').val();
      price = roundNumber(price,2);
      isNaN(price) ? row.find('.price').html("N/A") : row.find('.price').html("₱" +price);

      update_total();
      update_balance();
      update_ftotal();

    }

function update_total() {
      var total = 0;
      $('.price').each(function(i){
        price = $(this).html().replace("₱" ,"");
        if (!isNaN(price)) total += Number(price);
      });

  total = roundNumber(total,2);

  $('#subtotal').html("₱" +total);
  //$('#total').html("₱"+total); 

}

function update_balance() {
  var tax = $("#subtotal").html().replace("₱" ,"") * (0.12);
  tax = roundNumber(tax,2);

  $('.tax').html("₱" +tax);
}

function update_ftotal() {
  var sub , ax = 0;
  var sub = $("#subtotal").html();
  var ax = $('.tax').html();

  var due = sub + ax

  // due = roundNumber(due,2);

   $('.due').html(due);
}
```

here's the frontend where i use the class and id in the function

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="total-line">Subtotal:</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal" name="subtotal"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="3" class="total-line">12% Tax:</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div class="tax" id="tax"></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="blank"> </td> <!-- add tax result to the subtotal to get final total -->
        <td colspan="3" class="total-line balance">Total:</td>
        <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due" id="due"></div></td>
    </tr>
```

the result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKzjm.png)

Comment: Can you also show where/how you call the functions please?

Comment: yeah. already included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer.

```
function update_ftotal() {

  var sub , ax = 0;
  var sub =  $(".subtotal").html(); 
  var ax =  $(".tax").html();

  var num1 = Number(sub);
  var num2 = Number(ax);

  var due = num1 + num2;

  due = roundNumber(due,2);

  $('.due').html(due);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

sub and ax are strings, thus the plus operator concatenates them.

Try this:

```
var due = parseFloat(sub) + parseFloat(ax);
```

Comment: it returns a NAN

Comment: Then your divs do not contain numerical values.

Comment: it has. it came from the function of the ax and sub

Comment: ₱0.12 is not a numeral. 0.12 is.